# How to create effects using JavaScript when opening/closing treeview menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I want to add effects using JavaScript to this treeview. For example, adding a delay effect when opening menu items, meaning that they will open after a second of clicking on them, and displaying a loading icon when clicking on the (ul / li) items in the treeview. Additionally, I want to add the same effects when closing treeview items.

```js
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function(o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined') {
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined') {
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

    //initialize each of the top levels
    var tree = $(this);
    tree.addClass("tree");
    tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function() {
      var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
      branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
      branch.addClass('branch');
      branch.on('click', function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {
          var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
          icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
          $(this).children().children().toggle();
        }
      })
      branch.children().children().toggle();
    });
    //fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>a').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
    tree.find('.branch>button').each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('li').click();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({
  openedClass: 'fa-folder-open',
  closedClass: 'fa-folder'
});
```

```css
.tree,
.tree ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.tree ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative
}

.tree ul ul {
  margin-left: .5em
}

.tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid
}

.tree li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
}

.tree ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0
}

.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background: #fff;
  height: auto;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 0
}

.indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #369;
}

.tree li button,
.tree li button:active,
.tree li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #369;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul id="tree2">
      <li>
        <a href="#">TECH</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Company Maintenance</li>
          <li>
            Employees
            <ul>
              <li>
                Reports
                <ul>
                  <li>Report1</li>
                  <li>Report2</li>
                  <li>Report3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Employee Maint.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Human Resources</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        XRP
        <ul>
          <li>Company Maintenance</li>
          <li>
            Employees
            <ul>
              <li>
                Reports
                <ul>
                  <li>Report1</li>
                  <li>Report2</li>
                  <li>Report3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Employee Maint.</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Human Resources</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you call `.toggle()` you can just pass a number of milliseconds in there for a transition effect length. `.toggle(300)`  Simple!

However, using `.slideToggle(300)` will look better.

If you want to add a fake loader with a delay on each click, just add the loader element, wait, then remove it and the do the slideToggle

```
$(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner'></span> Loading...</div>");         
setTimeout(()=>{
  $(this).find('.loading').remove();
  $(this).children().children().slideToggle(300);
}, 300)
```

Here's the demo with that added:

```js
$.fn.extend({
    treed: function (o) {

      var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
      var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

      if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
        if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
        openedClass = o.openedClass;
        }
        if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
        closedClass = o.closedClass;
        }
      };

        //initialize each of the top levels
        var tree = $(this);
        tree.addClass("tree");
        tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
            var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
            branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
            branch.addClass('branch');
            branch.on('click', function (e) {
                if (this == e.target) {
                    var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                    icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner'></span> Loading...</div>");         
                      setTimeout(()=>{
                        $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                        $(this).children().children().slideToggle(300);
                      }, 300)
                }
            })
            branch.children().children().toggle();
        });
        //fire event from the dynamically added icon
      tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $(this).closest('li').click();
        });
      });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
        tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
.tree, .tree ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.tree ul {
  margin-left:1em;
  position:relative
}
.tree ul ul {
  margin-left:.5em
}
.tree ul:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:1px solid
}
.tree li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 1em;
  line-height:2em;
  color:#369;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
}
.tree ul li:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:10px;
  height:0;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin-top:-1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:1em;
  left:0
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background:#fff;
  height:auto;
  top:1em;
  bottom:0
}
.indicator {
  margin-right:5px;
}
.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
}
.tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
  border:none;
  background:transparent;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.loading {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <ul id="tree2">
          <li>
             <a href="#">TECH</a>
             <ul>
                <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                <li>
                   Employees
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                         Reports
                         <ul>
                            <li>Report1</li>
                            <li>Report2</li>
                            <li>Report3</li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Human Resources</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
             XRP
             <ul>
                <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                <li>
                   Employees
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                         Reports
                         <ul>
                            <li>Report1</li>
                            <li>Report2</li>
                            <li>Report3</li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Human Resources</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: a loading icon should be added when opening treeview (ul / li).